# Requirements for file input for Google Panorama API

Tags: android, google-play-services, panoramas, xmp

All the documentation says is this:

> *uri*   the URI of the panorama to load info about. May be a file:, content:,
>   or android_resource: scheme.

As file I think this could be a JPG which contains an ecuirectangular projection of the panorama, but is this correct and what would be the ideal imagesize? Is there a max? Is the maximum imagesize different per device?

I also read something about XMP data that has to be embed in the JPG, can I do without or is it mandatory?

Comment: What the process are you doing here? You wanna add a JPG and info for the input for `Google Panorama API`?

Comment: @bijang to show it in 3d spherical view, yes :)